# TypeScript: Extend Object.prototype and reference this

Tags: typescript

First the code snippet I try to get to work:

```
// taken from https://github.com/TheDavidDelta/scope-extensions-js and https://stackoverflow.com/a/65808350/2080707

declare global {
    /**
     * let calls the specified function block with `this` value as its argument and returns its result
     * @param fn - The function to be executed with `this` as argument
     * @returns `fn`'s result
     */
    interface Object {
        let<R>(fn: (val: this) => R): R;
    }
}

Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'let', {
    value(fn) {
        return fn(this);
    },
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
});
```

And now what I try to achieve:

`({ a: 'foobar' }).let((obj) => console.debug(obj.a))`
Of course this example is contrived and doesn't make much sense. But there are some cases where it does.

My problem is that let's argument is of type `object` and not of type `{a:string}`.
For this I need to reference the object whichs prototype got extended and not object itself.
Any pointer would be helpful :pray:

Edit: One could adapt https://github.com/HerbLuo/babel-plugin-kotlish-also to be able to support `let` as well. But it creates a lot of function overhead as well I guess.

Comment: Ick, modifying `Object.prototype` is very naughty, but I guess you're not asking for advice about that.  And do note that `{a: "foobar"}.let` is not valid syntax; you will need to wrap that in parentheses to `({a: "foobar"}).let`.  Anyway, I'm looking around to see if I can find a reason why polymorphic `this` doesn't automatically work the way you want here.  Does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/mAVb1W) meet your needs instead?  If so I can write up an answer. If not, please [edit] the code example to show what the issue is.

Comment: Indeed it is naugthy. But calling `let({a: 'foobar})((obj) => ...)` somehow just doesn't feel right. It is also possible to use babel to transform but I guess all the function mingeling does'nt make performance better.
Thank you very much for your code snippet. It perfectly fits. I don't understand why `let` doesn't expect the object as first parameter as required by the types. But it works :)

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the outset, as you know, [it is considered bad practice to extend native prototypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice) this way.  I will not belabor the point here, but I would be remiss if I did not officially discourage using this technique in any production code.

---

With that out of the way: you are trying to use [the polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) to represent the actual type of the object on which you call the `let()` method, which is almost certainly going to be narrower than `Object`.

Unfortunately, as you've seen, the compiler eagerly evaluates `this` to be `Object` when you call `let()`.  I haven't found authoritative documentation that says that this happens or why (although I'm almost sure I've seen something like this before; I'll keep looking and update if I find it), but [this comment in microsoft/TypeScript#40704](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40704#issuecomment-697044941) is evocative: `this` types are *expensive*.  They are essentially implicit [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters, and whenever you use one in a class or interface it imposes a compiler performance penalty.  My suspicion is that native types like `Object` this are not treated as potentially extra generic because to do so would affect all object types everywhere and the penalty would be severe.

---

Luckily, we can work around it.  Instead of using `this` as an implicit generic, we can make an *explicit* generic `T` and use a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters) of type `T` in the `let()` method:

```
interface Object {
    let<R, T>(this: T, fn: (val: T) => R): R;
}
        
({ a: 'foobar' }).let((obj) => console.debug(obj.a)) // okay now
```

I first saw this sort of technique used in [a comment on microsoft/TypeScript#5863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863#issuecomment-242782664), to work around a similar limitation whereby polymorphic `this` types are not available inside `static` class methods.

Note that [the same comment from before in microsoft/TypeScript#40704](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40704#issuecomment-697044941) actually says that `this` *types* are expensive, but `this` *parameters* are cheap.  So presumably this workaround is viable because of such "economic" factors.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/PTAEBMFMGMBsEMBOlQHNYHsBG9agN4BQAlgHYAukiAZvNCgPJYBWM5BhoXosk5APACUANKAAqAPgAU5ABbEAzgC5xo6qRVSAbrhViAlKAC8E0IP0rBAbkIBfQiFD3CTVtHIA6KNTKQACogYAA5U5ACeUq5sHkGB5BjhIaIA5LzkyaJE3KA6sACukFLqKvCkYYZZ2dzI5HmIpKDqMvIK+jbZtsKc3NAYpD6odfBYvCrkiAVd2QDuiMTkw6Og45N2bYQbUvig8CrJ1BjYSMlO+h5pUlLYzIYmoL2kChi8XpBYeahXLB7w+vobGyAA)

Comment: A wonderful write up with the pointers I needed. Thank you very much!